# Cómo colocar los colores para django contrib messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Según [ésta documentación](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/1.6.x/django.pdf) la manera correcta de agregar un mensaje de *Django Contrib Messages* es:

[image: imn]

Y de ésta manera en el template:
[image: im1]

Sin embargo no puedo hacer que se pinten los mensajes con los colores apropiados, es decir, verde si es message de info o rojo si es message de error, lo que sucede es que todos los mensajes se pintan negros como un texto cualquiera:

[image: im2]

Podrían por favor indicarme si es distinto para Django 1.6 y para Django 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

No es con Django, eso es directamente en tu hoja de estilos. La forma en la que usas tu plantilla, indica que tu hoja de estilos debe tener una forma como la siguiente:

```
.debug {
  color: yellow;
}

.info {
  color: green;
}
```

Para saber más sobre las hojas de estilos, consulta esta página: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.es.html

Answer (score 0):

Nunca use Django 1.6, uso django 1.8 pero te puedo decir algo sobre los estilos. eso lo puedes hacer con javascript y cuando el mensaje aparece en pantalla esta dentro de un li y tendra una clase que es la que django le agrega selecciona esa clase con javascript le pones estilo con javascript.o puedes escribir un css y escribir los estilos para los mensajes de error django agrega una clase "errorlist" y supongo que para warning sera "warninglist". voy a suponer que sabes css y javascript.

Comment: no puedo no usar 1.6, es un proyecto que ya está hecho así, y no, no soy experta, apenas estoy aprendiendo